# Structuring my Java Swing application. I.E. when and where to use classes and not

Tags: java, swing, class, methods, constructor

I continue on to adding action listeners to my Java Swing buttons and fields etc. I would like to know where and when I should separate the code into classes and different methods. Unfortunately right now my code feels like it is one long script like I am used to creating in Python instead of an OOP language like Java.

How do I separate this code into classes and methods more appropriately?

Here is the code in question:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package business;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import static java.awt.Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;


/**
 *
 * @author bob
 */
public class NewClass {


    //Initialize GUI elements
    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();



    JTree jtree1 = new JTree();
    JTree jtree2 = new JTree();

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the person tester application");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Test2");
    JLabel spacer1 = new JLabel("");
    JLabel spacer2 = new JLabel("");
    //buttons

    JRadioButton radioCustomer = new JRadioButton("Customer");
    JRadioButton radioEmployee = new JRadioButton("Employee");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JButton okButton = new JButton();
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Create");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("EXIT");


    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(jtree1);
    JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane(jtree2);

    //Panels
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();

    JPanel createPanel = new JPanel();


    //Constructor
    public NewClass(){

    }


    //The createGUI method is inside the class so we can reference the GUI objects created above
    public void createGUI(){

    //Buttons

    button2.setToolTipText("Create");
    button3.setToolTipText("Exit");
    button3.setForeground(Color.red);
    button3.setAlignmentX(RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
    group.add(radioEmployee);
    group.add(radioCustomer);


    //Adding actionListeners
    GUIListener myListener = new GUIListener();
    okButton.addActionListener(myListener);
    button2.addActionListener(myListener);
    button3.addActionListener(myListener);




    //adding to and customizing the panels


    createPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(createPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        createPanel.add(radioEmployee);
    createPanel.add(radioCustomer);
    createPanel.add(button2);


    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    panel2.add(label1);
    panel2.add(createPanel);



    panel3.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp);
    panel3.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, sp2);


    panel4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel4, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    panel4.add(spacer1);
    panel4.add(button3);





    //adding panels to main panel
    mainPanel.add(panel2);
    mainPanel.add(panel3);
    mainPanel.add(panel4);

    //adding panels we created to the frame


    myFrame.add(mainPanel);



    //setting some parameters to customize the frame

    myFrame.setSize(600, 400);
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
}



        public class GUIListener implements ActionListener{
        @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == okButton){
                label1.setText("okButton was pushed!");

            }
            else if (e.getSource() == button2){

            }


            else if (e.getSource() == button3){


               System.out.println("button3 was pusshed");

            }
        }
    }

    //main method that makes the program run
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       //instantiate an object of the NewClass class
       NewClass GUI = new NewClass();

       //Use the method to create and display the GUI
       GUI.createGUI();
   }

}
```

Comment: Python is an OOP language.

Comment: [codereview.se](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place when it comes to coding-style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, in-of-itself, is not a easy thing to do and recognising when you should comes a lot from experience (oh, I remember last time I did this, it was horrible to manage and maintain ), but, there is a lot of available patterns which are used everyday to make software development easier and solve everyday common problems.

One thing you need to keep in mind is who has the responsibility to do what.  For example, it might not be possible to seperate the action listeners of the buttons, as they need to perform operations which are internal to the UI itself.

However, you could make it easier through the use of [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) or even the [Actions API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), which allows to isolate the functionality of the button

Another thing I would look at is isolating all the seperate containers (panels) to their own classes.  This isolates the functionality and reduces the amount of complexity as it forces you to think about how each sub container is going to work and what it becomes responsible for as well as reducing unnecessary access from external influences.

A more complex solution would have the UI rely on a "model", which separated from the UI.  The UI would then take actions from the user and update the model, which would intern generate notifications that the UI would use to update itself to reflect the changes, see [Model-View-Controller](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm) for more details

So, what's the answer?

- Break your data apart from the UI. Use one or more container/model classes to represent the data.  Make use of the [observer pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) to allow the model to generate events when changes occur so interested parties can take appropriate action
- Break down your UI into "usable" components, where each component is isolated and responsible for managing a single portion of the UI (and how that happens is it's own business)
- I would also recommend making use of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to share objects between the separated elements, this will allow you to isolate and test individual areas of your code, bonus, which also leads into...
- [Test Driven Development (TDD)](https://technologyconversations.com/2013/12/20/test-driven-development-tdd-example-walkthrough/). Know what and how you want to test your code before you try and design it

Comment: A great post overall and about as good as one can get in eight short paragraphs.  Whole books get written on best practice and how to decompose software.  One thing MadProgrammer didn't mention is testing.  It's often good to get your testing requirements up front and design your code so that it is easy to test.  This leads to the type of breakdown that M.P. describes above, but it's important to remember why you want to decompose code this way, and it's often to make parts of it easier to test.